# Select first item in Silverlight combobox using MVVM pattern

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, combobox

This is my first foray in MVVM and I've now encountered the following issue:

I've got my ViewModel:

```
  public List<WorkCellGroupInfo> WorkCellGroupInfoCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _workCellGroupInfoCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _workCellGroupInfoCollection = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged( "WorkCellGroupInfoCollection" );

            SelectedWorkCellGroup = _workCellGroupInfoCollection.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public WorkCellGroupInfo SelectedWorkCellGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedWorkCellGroup;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedWorkCellGroup = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged( "SelectedWorkCellGroup" );
        }
    }
```

and my XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="WorkCellGroup" 
ItemsSource="{Binding WorkCellGroupInfoCollection}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWorkCellGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Name">
```

On the first load the combobox gets populated with the data but I can't get the first item selected. What am I doing wrong?

The WorkCellGroupInfo is derived from the FilterBase class:

```
public abstract class FilterBase
{
    public string Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a value to `SelectedWorkCellGroup` property to do that.

In you ViewModel's constructor, write following code:

```
if(WorkCellGroupInfoCollection.Any()) 
{
    SelectedWorkCellGroup = WorkCellGroupInfoCollection.First();
}
```

### Edit:

Following works for me:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="White">
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox x:Name="WorkCellGroup"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding WorkCellGroupInfoCollection}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWorkCellGroup, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class ComboBoxSelectedItemTest : UserControl
{
    public ComboBoxSelectedItemTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ComboBoxSelectedItemTestViewModel();
    }
}

public abstract class FilterBase
{
    public string Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class WorkCellGroupInfo : FilterBase
{ }

public class WorkCellGroupInfoCollection : ObservableCollection<WorkCellGroupInfo>
{ }

public class ComboBoxSelectedItemTestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public WorkCellGroupInfoCollection WorkCellGroupInfoCollection { get; set; }

    public ComboBoxSelectedItemTestViewModel()
    {
        WorkCellGroupInfoCollection = new WorkCellGroupInfoCollection();

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            WorkCellGroupInfoCollection.Add(new WorkCellGroupInfo()
            {
                Id = String.Format("Id #{0}", i + 1),
                Name = String.Format("Name #{0}", i + 1)
            });
        }

        SelectedWorkCellGroup = WorkCellGroupInfoCollection.First();
    }

    private WorkCellGroupInfo _selectedWorkCellGroup;
    public WorkCellGroupInfo SelectedWorkCellGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedWorkCellGroup;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedWorkCellGroup = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedWorkCellGroup");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was fast! Let me try that out and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I've added that code to the ViewModel's constructor in the ViewModel class but still nothing happens. Can you pelase advise?

Comment: Do you get any binding errors in Output window? And also you need to put above code after you populate `WorkCellGroupInfoCollection` collection.

Comment: @decyclone Hi no I don't get any binding errors in the output window and I've put the code after the WorkCellGroupInfoCollection has been populated.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your class definition for `WorkCellGroupInfo`?

Comment: @decyclone Wow thanks for that! I will give that a go when I have time as I've now been sidetracked.

Comment: @decyclone: My apologies for not getting back to you. We have now "abandoned" Silverlight for the moment. I can't quite remember but I don't think that worked and it might have more to do with other things rather than SL.